# Why Golang is faster than ANSI C and how can I optimize my solution?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, go, optimization

I wrote benchmarks to check how fast if statements can be handled by `Golang` and `ANSI C` respectively. I was trying to keep the same schema overall solutions.

Solution in **ANSI C** is following;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void bench(void (*f)(int));
void if_func_1(int i);
void if_func_2(int i);
void if_func_3(int i);

int main() {
        bench(&if_func_1);
        bench(&if_func_2);
        bench(&if_func_3);

        return 0;
}

void bench(void (*f)(int)) {
        int i;
        struct timespec start, end;
        float delta_us;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);

        for (i = 2147483647; -2147483648 != i; i--) {
            (*f)(i);
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);
        delta_us = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) * 0.001;
        printf("%.3fms\n", delta_us * 0.001);
}

void if_func_1(int i) {
    if (0 == i) {
        return;
    }

    if (1 == i) {
        return;
    }

    if (2 == i) {
        return;
    }

    if (3 == i) {
        return;
    }

    return;
}

void if_func_2(int i) {
    if (0 == i) {
        return;
    } else if (1 == i) {
        return;
    } else if (2 == i) {
        return;
    } else if (3 == i) {
        return;
    }

    return;
}

void if_func_3(int i) {
    if (0 == i || 1 == i || 2 == i || 3 == i) {
        return;
    }

    return;
}
```

The results were folowing:

```
~ time ./app.bin
20875.278ms
28766.584ms
16371.974ms
./app.bin  65.59s user 0.09s system 99% cpu 1:06.02 total
```

As I expected `if_func_3` was the fastest one because it implements different logic.

In **Golang** my solutions is following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    bench(if_func_1)
    bench(if_func_2)
    bench(if_func_3)
}

func bench(f func(int)) {
    var i int = 0

    start := time.Now();
    for i = 2147483647; -2147483648 != i; i-- {
        f(i)
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(elapsed)

}

func if_func_1(i int) {
    if 0 == i {
        return
    }

    if 1 == i {
        return
    }

    if 2 == i {
        return
    }

    if 3 == i {
        return
    }

    return
}

func if_func_2(i int) {
    if 0 == i {
        return
    } else if 1 == i {
        return
    } else if 2 == i {
        return
    } else if 3 == i {
        return
    }

    return
}

func if_func_3(i int) {
    if 0 == i || 1 == i || 2 == i || 3 == i {
        return
    }

    return
}
```

I could use pointers here because they don't exist in Golang.

Resutls are quite confusing.

```
~> time go run app.go
11.595459054s
13.062146816s
14.504122183s
go run app.go  39.33s user 0.34s system 92% cpu 42.746 total
```

What causes such difference in these two solutions? How can I optimize `ANSI C` solution to perform better?

**Enviroment specification**

> System MacOS
>
> gcc version 10.0.0
>
> go version 1.10.3

Compiled with `-ansi --pedantic -Wall` flags.

## Summary

After adding `-O` and changing the trivial `return` to print some text. Total execution timings have changed.

**For ANSI C**

```
From: System 99% cpu 1:06.02 total 
To: System 99% cpu 8.552 total
```

**For Golang**

```
From: system 98% cpu 43.634 total 
To: system 92% cpu 42.746 total
```

Comment: Go is no doubt performing optimizations that your C compiler is not.

Comment: Compiler version and compilation option make a huge difference in C at least (and presumably in Go too). As such your question is missing vital information.

Comment: But really, benchmarking something trivial like if statements outside of it's intended usage is pointless. Algorithm in which if statement is used dictates how well compiler can optimize it.

Comment: your functions don't do anything useful - they are all 100% equivalent to simply `return;`. If the optimizer notices that ... all bets are off.

Comment: @Flimzy Why is the reason of this? Look that, Go don't optimze `if_func_3` which gcc does. And `if_func_3` implements different (easier) logic.

Comment: You compiled the C code with no optimization.

Comment: @user694733 What if you need to choose a language to impelent the algoritm?

Comment: @IanAbbott How can I optimize it?

Comment: @AdmiringKnuth Then you need to benchmark and compare the *actual algorithms*. Benchmarking individual language features in isolation will not give you useful results.

Comment: Just a comment... even in PHP7 it's faster without optimization switch while compiling on C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your tested functions are trivially equivalent to `void no_op(int) {}`. The large timing differences are just possible because you are compiling without optimizations, which makes your benchmark results dubious at best.

Proper benchmarking requires turning on optimizations (i.e. `-O` or higher for GCC and Clang), and taking care that the relevant parts are, however, not optimized out. It can appear to be a simple problem, but is often surprisingly hard in practice. I recommend using a benchmarking library [such as google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) to make the problem a bit more manageable.

I see that you updated your question with compiler version and settings, which is a good thing. Performance-related questions tend to have either somewhat or highly implementation-dependent answers, so this information should always be included in this kind of question (for that matter, it never hurts for any question involving a test program). You should also add the version of and switches for Golang that you are using.

Comment: `gcc ./app.c -O --ansi --pedantic -Wall`  after run with `time ./a.out` gives `./a.out  0.00s user 0.00s system 53% cpu 0.012 total`.

Comment: @AdmiringKnuth one thing one should also remember is, gcc is clever enough and removes things which does no work.(when optimization is enabled)

Comment: @nilsocket I've realized it and change `return` to `print` in both implementations. Optimization worked perfectly, and in summary, I've added timings.

Comment: @AdmiringKnuth, if you are using `fmt.Printf` that is slow, but as said before, gcc is too clever, while enabling optimizations for c and comparing the same with go is also not good, better comparison would be to compile with gccgo, I have done and it also takes no time.

Comment: @nilsocket It did, but it gave an impression of efficiency ANSI C has over Golang.